# Transform a picture full of polygons shapes to code

Tags: css, typescript, react-native, shapes

I'm new to web/mobile app development. I'm using react-native.

I have a picture containing multiple polygonal shapes, let's say [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZBfN.png).

I'd like to transform each of theses shapes (in the picture) into multiple corresponding generated shape with code.
I know I could do this manually using `styles` properties (width, border, top, left etc) but I don't really wan't to break my brain on figuring how to achieve it for each shapes, considering that I'd like to render more than 100 different shapes extracted from a picture.

Is there a tool or something that can generate automatically the `styles` code from uploading a picture ?
Even if I could draw manually the shape in a picture editor, that then generate code, it would help me to save a lot of time.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect you'll end up doing them sort of by hand, have you investigated using cip path and a polygon. with % offsets it doesn't take a minute to define the simpler polygons at least and you'll have proper control of the results.

Comment: @AHaworth yeah guess I will do like this, I was hoping to found a tool that does this to me or at least allow to draw the polygon form above the layer of my picture and then generate some  code

Comment: TBH I find it more accurate to just do it by hand using % - especially where you have regular parts of the polygon, drawing is often not accurate enough.

Comment: I'm looking to use clip path as you said, but it doesn't seems compatible with react native unfortunatly. Using StyleSheet with multiple styles to perform a polygonal shape is really a mess for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found how I could do it, I'll just use the lib https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg